# Why does set() in set() not raise a TypeError, unlike {} in set(), [] in set(), set() in {}, [] in {}, or {} in {}?

Tags: python, set

Sets and dicts are unhashable thus can't contain sets, dicts, or lists as keys.  Even checking for containment raises a TypeError, as in all these five cases:

- `{} in {}`
- `[] in {}`
- `set() in {}`
- `{} in set()`
- `[] in set()`

but checking if a set contains a set does *not* raise a TypeError:

- `set() in set()`

returns False.

Why is `set() in set()` handled differently from `{} in {}`, `[] in {}`, `set() in {}`, `{} in set()`, or `[] in set()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While sets can't contain sets, they can contain frozensets.  For example,

```
>>> s = {frozenset({2, 3}), frozenset({5, 7})}
>>> s
{frozenset({2, 3}), frozenset({5, 7})}
>>> type(s)
<class 'set'>
```

So `s` contains frozensets, but is not itself a frozenset.  Now in this:

```
>>> {7, 5} in s
True
```

the [implementation of `set.__contains__()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.4/Objects/setobject.c#L1854-L1872) first tries to see whether `{7, 5}` is in `s`.  That raises a `TypeError` ("key not hashable") internally.  If checking for a key raises a type error, *and* the key is of a set type (or set subtype), then the implementation clears that error, builds a temporary frozenset from the original key, and tries again.

[It is documented](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c01da2896ab92ba7193bcd6ae56908c5c7277e75/Doc/library/stdtypes.rst#L4406-L4408), at the bottom of the [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.clear) type:

> Note, the elem argument to the `__contains__()`, `remove()`, and `discard()` methods may be a set. To support searching for an equivalent frozenset, a temporary one is created from elem.

Offhand, I would not have done that (too magical), but perhaps there was some compelling use case I'm unaware of.

Comment: Another possibility would have been to return `False` in all of those cases.  *Does my set contain this dict?* is easily answered: *No, silly, sets can't contain dicts -> `False`*. After all, `a == b` never raises an exception either, at least not for built-in types.  But it would not surprise me if that dates back to Python 0.9.

Comment: Cross-type comparison is _very_ different between Pythons 2 and 3.  Unless overridden, in Python 3 cross-type `==` always returns `False`, cross-type `!=` always `True`, and the other 4 comparison operators always raise `TypeError`.  This was first pioneered late in Python 2's life with the then-new `datetime` module's types.  In Python 2, cross-type comparisons, unless overridden, fell back to comparing the types' string names; e.g., `3453345 < "2"` because `"int" < "str"`.

Comment: For consistently, one might argue the same behaviour for `dict_keys` and `dict`, which can also contain frozensets or have those as keys.